# How to manipulate text file in WebPages (cshtml)?

Tags: c#, file-io, asp.net-webpages

How to manipulate file using WebPages (.cshtml)? In PHP we have `fopen` and other functions, what are the counterparts?

Comment: Note that modifying/creating CSHTML files is a code smell. It brings some risk (if data can be injected into the page that may be executed) and may lead to performance issues because of the dynamic compilation of the pages (no garbage collection is possible for the dynamically generated code).

Comment: @Lucero I'm sorry, what I mean is I'm using cshtml, I won't modify cshtml... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET you have the [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class. So for example if you wanted to read the contents of some text file in a variable:

```
@{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\work\foo.txt");
}
```

Comment: And... how to import that in WebPages? I'm using pure cshtml files, no cs files...

Comment: @domanokz, import what? WebPages is Razor syntax. `.cshtml` is C#. So you simply use `string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\work\foo.txt");`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I should import the namespace. Thanks!

Comment: @domanokz, you could use the `<namespaces>` section of your web.config to define commonly used namespaces in your Razor pages. You could also do a `@using System.IO` on the top of your Razor page.